# Google Graphs and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, graph, echo

I am want to show a line graph that get information from a table in a database. I came across Google Graphs which seems to be the best for what i need. I can get the graph to show data i place in the code but when i try to use echo to add data from the database it does not work. Please find below my code. I am not sure what i have done wrong here.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Products');
        data.addRows([
<!--CHANGE FOR PHP TO PULL INFORMATION FRO MYSQL DBA-->

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");
$start = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "['".$row["dateadded"]."', ".$row["products"]."],";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Product Count History',
                       'width':600  ,
                       'height':550};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_product_history'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>


                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                <div id="chart_product_history"></div>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">

                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td width="50%">

                </td>
                <td width="50%">

                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
```

Thanks Ryan

Comment: Have you made sure the data is being pulled from the database correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with some fixed random data and it did produce a graph (although you have an extra comma in the array that might cause issues sometimes).

You appear to be missing the closing curly bracket from the loop around the results of the query.

Try the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Products');
        data.addRows([
<!--CHANGE FOR PHP TO PULL INFORMATION FRO MYSQL DBA-->

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");
$start = 0;
$OutArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $OutArray[] = "['".$row["dateadded"]."', ".$row["products"]."],";
}

echo explode(',', $OutArray);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Product Count History',
                       'width':600  ,
                       'height':550};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_product_history'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>


                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                <div id="chart_product_history"></div>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">

                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td width="50%">

                </td>
                <td width="50%">

                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked i also had to change my php for getting from the table so it would work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
 echo "['".$row["dateadded"]."', ".$row["products"]."],";
```

to this:

```
 echo "['".$row['dateadded']."', '".$row['products']."'],";
```

Comment: Hi @Paddyd Sorry but this did not work. the page still does not load. Thanks

Comment: Do you know for sure that your database call is working properly? Try pull the same data and echo it outside of the chart to make sure that is not the problem.

Comment: I think this may be the issue just tried it outside of the graph and it does not work but looking at it, it should work

Comment: stick your php code in a file of its own and echo the results as you are doing above. If nothing is being echoed then that is your problem